# How can we set the regional settings to EN-GB for the English language pack?

Tags: 2013, multilingual, regional-settings, language-pack

We have a multiple language packs installed on our SP2013 farm, the default language is English (this is EN-US).

We would like to use the EN-GB regional settings for English but it looks like the regional settings are ignored when language packs are installed (this makes sense because the regional settings are linked to the active language.)
Unfortunately, there is no EN-GB language pack available. Does that mean that there is no way to use English with EN-GB regional settings once language packs have been installed?

Changing the regional settings on a site with no language packs installed works fine.